# onsuccess of remoteCommand not working properly after upgrade to Primefaces 3.5

Tags: javascript, primefaces

After upgrading from 2.2.1 I'm not able to show some data from a view scoped backing bean inside a dialog component any longer. The dialog pop ups, but the data from the bean is set to null.

The problem seems to be that the remotecommand of the button calls a javascript that again calls the show method on the dialog widget. The render response phase is called twice through to the process(The restore view phase is only called once). First time with the correct values, and second with null values.

If I change the onsucess attribute to show the dialog directly:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="lazyload" onsuccess="confirmdialog.show();"
update=":confirm"  >
```

the dialog shows the values correctly. If I instead use the handleConfirm script from the onsuccess attribute and comment out the "return true;" from the javascript the dialog also shows the values. Render phase is now only called once.

Any ideas as to why this could trigger an extra render phase would be highly appreciated.

I'm a bit reluctant removing the javascript. It's the code of a former collegue, and I can't find anything in the application where the data parameter for the javascript is set. I'm a bit unsure if the reason is lack of understanding on my behalf or fishy code. alert(data.text); returns undefined.

**Code:**

BuyProduct.xhtml that contains the remote command:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:comp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components">


    <ui:include src="/confirmOrder.xhtml"/>

    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton disabled="#{productsearch.hasCP == false}" 
        onclick="if(canhide == false) {return false;} if(submitelement!=this||cansubmit==false) { cansubmit = false; submitelement=this; lazyload(); return false;} cansubmit = false; submitelement=null; canhide=false; loading.show(); return true;"
            ajax="false" value="${msgs.order}"
            actionListener="#{cp.PerformSearch}"
            action="/services/cPReply.xhtml">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{confirmorder.targetGateway}" target="#{cp.gateway}" />
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{productsearch.code}" target="#{cp.code}" />
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{productsearch.registerId}" target="#{cp.registerId}" />
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:remoteCommand name="lazyload" onsuccess="return handleConfirm(data);" update=":confirm"  >  
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{productsearch.cPGW.gateway_id}" target="#{confirmorder.gatewayId}" />
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="CP" target="#{confirmorder.serviceName}" />

        </p:remoteCommand>
```

confirmOrder.xhtml that contains the javascript and dialog:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

    <script>
        var cansubmit = false;
        var submitelement = null;

        function handleConfirm(data)
        {
            if(data.getElementsByTagName("error") != null &amp;&amp; data.getElementsByTagName("error")[0] != null) {
                sessiontimeout.show();
                return false;
            }
            else {

                    confirmdialog.show();
            }

            return true;
        }

    </script>


    <p:dialog header="${msgs.buyProducts}" widgetVar="confirmdialog" id="confirmdialogiden"
        modal="true" resizable="false" width="700" dynamic="true">
        <h:panelGrid id="confirm">
            <f:view beforePhase="#{confirmorder.beforePhase}" afterPhase="#{confirmorder.afterPhase}">
            <ui:debug hotkey="x"></ui:debug>
            <h:panelGrid id="noProductSelected" rendered="#{confirmorder.size==false}">
                ${msgs.noProductSelected}
                </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid id="productSelected" columns="2" rules="cols" rendered="#{confirmorder.size}" >
                    <h:panelGrid width="400" id="productSelectedSub">

                        <b>${msgs.products}</b>

                        <p:dataList value="#{confirmorder.products}" var="car">
                #{car.product_description}, #{car.price_nok}  
                        </p:dataList>

                        <p:separator /> 
                        <b>${msgs.amount} </b>
                        <h:outputText id="total" value="#{confirmorder.sum} " />
                    </h:panelGrid>

            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGrid>
      </:dialog>
```

Primefaces 3.5 | Mojarra 2.1.19 | Weblogic 10.3.3

Comment: What are you trying to do by returning `true` or `false` from onsuccess method here?

Comment: Removing the return resolved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I will add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `return` values from `onsuccess` in this case. Returning false will cancel default DOM update process so I think this is problem in your case.